# How to zoom only on the X axis in a line chart in d3.js (v7)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can apply a zoom to a path in d3v7. However, how can I zoom only in the x-axis instead of a standard zoom?

(1) How I call the zoom function:

```
var svgArea = d3.select('#svg');
const path = svgArea.append("path");
const line = d3.line()
    .x(d => scale.x(d.sample))
    .y(d => scale.y(d.value));
path
    .datum(dataset)
    .attr("fill", fillColor)
    .attr("stroke", color)
    .attr("d", line);
svgArea.call(zoom, padding, width, height, path);
```

(2) Zoom Function

```
function zoom(svg, padding, width, height, path) {

    var extent = [
        [padding, padding],
        [width, height]
    ];

    var zooming = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 3])
        .translateExtent(extent)
        .extent(extent)
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    svg.call(zooming);

    function zoomed(e) {
        path.attr("transform", e.transform);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your zoom function, you can rescale the x axis, and then use that to redraw the entire graph:

```
const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom", function(event) {
    x2 = event.transform.rescaleX(x); 
    xAxisG.call(xAxis.scale(x2));
    path.attr("d", line);
  })
```

`x2` refers to a working scale (which is used with d3.line() as well). The scale `x` is used as a reference scale for the rescaling (we don't want to rescale `x2` using itself as then we get the wrong zoom value). By doing this we only manipulate the x values while the y values remain the same.

Below I've added a clipping path to stop the graph from overflowing from the plot area.

*You can't use the zoom transform itself to manipulate the graph as it applies the same scaling value to both x and y axes. It only zooms geometry. The approach proposed here is a semantic zoom: using the data and rescaling it in one dimension given the state of a zoom transform.*

Here's a working example:

```js
const width = 500;
const height = 180;
const padding = {top: 10, bottom: 50, left: 40, right: 20};

const svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", width + padding.right + padding.left)
  .attr("height", height + padding.top + padding.bottom)
  
const plotArea = svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate("+[padding.left,padding.top]+")")  

const clippingRect = plotArea
  .append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clippy")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height)
  .attr("fill","none")

  
const data = d3.range(100).map(function(d) {
  return { value: Math.random(), sample: d }
})

const x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,width]).domain([0,100]);
let x2 = x.copy();
const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height,0]).domain([0,1]);

const line = d3.line()
    .x(d => x2(d.sample))
    .y(d => y(d.value));
    
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x2);
const xAxisG = plotArea.append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate("+[0,height]+")")
  .call(xAxis);
  
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
const yAxisG = plotArea.append("g").call(yAxis)

  
const path = plotArea.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("d", line)
  .attr("clip-path","url(#clippy)")
  
 
const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom", function(event) {
    x2 = event.transform.rescaleX(x); 
    xAxisG.call(xAxis.scale(x2));
    path.attr("d", line);
  })

svg.call(zoom);
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.1.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: How would yo use this approach for multiple paths? Let's say your data array is an array of objects (e.g. [{name: foo, value:[]]}, {name: bar, value:[]). Then you add the data to your path(s) with
 .data(data)
  .attr("d", d => {
    return line(d.value)
  }) 
instead of datum. Upon zooming the x axis does rescale, but the path doesn't move. What other steps are needed? Thanks!

Comment: I found the solution here: https://observablehq.com/@radames/multi-line-chart-zoom